# PHP Security, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Tags: php, api, rest

**Background:**
I am creating a REST api, that will require users to use only a JavaScript file, for that I made an ajax request that gets data from the server.
in order to do that I wrote the following like in php:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

**I have a few questions:**
1) What is the security hole that is present if I open the ability of other domains to       interact with me?
(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)
2) What should I do to secure it?
3) Does this "Allow-Origin" work in all browsers? (mobile...) - or it does not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the wildcard, that means any domain can make a cross domain request to your domain and get the page. For example, say you are logged into your GMail account. Naturally, when you open up a window to http://gmail.com, you will instantly see your emails and messages (there's some redirection happening, but let's assume not for the sake of the example and simplicity).

Well if I make a website (be it anything) and I manage to get you on that website, or alternatively, I manage to modify a website that you frequently go on, I could make an AJAX request to GMail, and if GMail had Allow-Origin: * and you were logged in, the AJAX request would return the HTML of the page that is usually shown to you; the list of your emails. At worst I get a list of all your emails and the persons you sent them to, at best I can also manipulate the requests and get a lot more information.

I wouldn't use a wildcard if I were you; I would use some sort of list of trusted domains.

The Allow Origin is enforced server side. As for cross origin AJAX support, it is supported in most browsers. For older versions of IE, you have to use a different object to make the requests.

Comment: Can you show me an example of an attack? I just don't get it yet...(can you access the php itself?

Comment: @agam360, I edited my post with a clearer explanation. Does that make more sense?

Comment: So you say that I should scan the website and check if it's on the "white list"? Can people then fake themselves?(What function should I use?)

Comment: @agam360 Well this is only enforced client-side. Meaning the browser will decide whether or not to make the request. What you're trying to protect is your clients from getting their authenticated data stolen if they're logged in. If you have any session based / authentication stuff, just don't use `*`, and instead have a list of valid domains.

Comment: I am basically giving the user a string (which should be public afterwards) and I want to limit the times the user can generate this string, that is all.

Comment: Is there any session / login procedure? Are the "states" a user can be in?

Comment: not really, but this does interest me(as I am going to use this in a bigger scale), are there any articles on attacks of such kind? (I couldn't find some)

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm only saying that from my understanding. Maybe someone else will have something.